# Как переставить в обратном порядке элементы столбцов квадратной матрицы, которые расположены ниже ее главной диагонали?

Tags: массивы, матрицы

Задана квадратная матрица. Как переставить в обратном порядке элементы тех столбцов матрицы, которые расположены ниже ее главной диагонали ?

```
void Matrix::reverse()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < N/2; i++)
  { 
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
      if (i>j)
      {
        int tmp = a[i][j];
        a[i][j] = a[N-i][j];
        a[N-i][j] = tmp;
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Первый столбец нормально выводит в обратном порядке, следующий меняет по половине, а остальные вообще не меняет, не знаю в чём проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Вы проходитесь вглубь только на половину, этот вариант бы подошел, если бы надо было поменять верхние ряды ... Так что надо делать скорее всего как-то так (лень конвертить обратно, да и так нагляднее):

```js
const a = [
  [11,21,31,41,51,61],
  [12,22,32,42,52,62],
  [13,23,33,43,53,63],
  [14,24,34,44,54,64],
  [15,25,35,45,55,65],
  [16,26,36,46,56,66]
];
const N = a.length;

for (let i = N - 1; i > N/2; i--){ 
  for (let j = 0; j < N; j++){
    if (i>j) {
      const tmp = a[i][j];
      a[i][j] = a[N+j-i][j];
      a[N+j-i][j] = tmp;
    }   
  }
}

console.log(a);
```